# What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?

Tags: discussion, faq, answering-questions, canonical

We've created, appointed, or otherwise identified certain question/answer pairs that are the [canonical answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) for certain problems.  These are answers where the community has said all it is going to say on a class of subject, because although everyone's particular problems in that class are somewhat different, to the extent that they are interesting, they aren't different, and to the extent that they're different, they aren't interesting (to anyone save the questioner). So we write one answer that's designed to be the last word on the subject, and say no more.

A list of these problems is given in the accepted answer below.

Please:

- Post an Answer to nominate a question for inclusion. Questions explicitly posted for the purpose of creating a canonical Question/Answer can skip this.
- Delete content that has been merged into the official list. Try to keep this post neat and tidy.

Comment: Who decides that a question is canonical? Anyone in the community?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Yes, and you can self Q&A with the intention of providing both the question and the answer. Other members of the community will step in and contribute better answers if they feel that the existing ones are insufficient. This has worked pretty well for us so far, and I imagine that the mods will step in if someone tries to abuse this. (a "canonical" Q&A that disregards the community isn't really canonical)

Comment: "A list of these problems is given in the accepted answer below." - only there's no accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 156):

These are the questions we have identified as Canonical:

### Capacity Planning

- Generic Capacity Planning: [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686)
- [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for databases?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350458)
- [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454)

### Career

- Starting out: [What a beginner should know/learn for sysadmin job?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9766)

### Databases

- [InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool](https://serverfault.com/questions/575991)

### Datacenter Design

- [What's the best fire suppression for a server room?](https://serverfault.com/q/25319)
- [Server room survival kit?](https://serverfault.com/q/2382)
- [What were your server room pain points, big wins and must haves?](https://serverfault.com/q/531516)
- [What to look for in a datacentre ethernet switch](https://serverfault.com/q/537384)

### Documentation

- [Getting started with documentation](https://serverfault.com/q/46273)

### EMail & Spam

- [How to stop people from using my domain to send spam?](https://serverfault.com/q/415533)
- [What are SPF records, and how do I configure them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369460/)
- [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/q/419407/126699)
- [Prevent mail being marked as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/227242)
- [How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428)

### Hardware

- [Why is Enterprise Storage so expensive?](https://serverfault.com/q/263694)
- [What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/q/339128)
- [What is a Storage Area Network, and which benefits does it have over different storage solutions?](https://serverfault.com/q/425335)
- [Rack Mount Servers - Build them or Buy them?](https://serverfault.com/q/15040/)

### Hosting provider/server hardware shopping

- [Dedicated server or Cloud Hosting?](https://serverfault.com/q/326205)
- [Use Google Apps/Cloud Services as a Domain Controller Replacement](https://serverfault.com/q/398335)

### Infrastructure Software

- [Can I have multiple DHCP servers on one network?](https://serverfault.com/q/368512)

#### Active Directory

- [What is Active Directory Domain Services and how does it work?](https://serverfault.com/q/402580)
- [What is Group Policy and how does it work?](https://serverfault.com/q/406240)
- [Windows Active Directory naming best practices?](https://serverfault.com/q/76715)
- [What should the order of DNS servers be for an AD Domain Controller and Why?](https://serverfault.com/q/394804)
- [Difference between Microsoft ADCS Standalone CA and Enterprise CA](https://serverfault.com/q/826444)

#### DNS

- [Should we host our own nameservers?](https://serverfault.com/q/23744)
- [How long does it take for DNS records to propagate?](https://serverfault.com/q/125371)
- [What is a glue record?](https://serverfault.com/q/309622)
- [How to use DNS/Hostnames or Other ways to resolve to a specific IP:Port](https://serverfault.com/q/74362)
- [Why does DNS work the way it does?](https://serverfault.com/q/355887)
- [Do internet standards require reverse DNS for every device?](https://serverfault.com/q/612833)
- [Is dig +trace always accurate?](https://serverfault.com/q/482913)
- [What is the role of NS records at the apex of a DNS domain?](https://serverfault.com/q/588244)
- [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/q/613829)
- [How do I understand my CPU usage on a DNS server?](https://serverfault.com/q/649559)
- [How can I manage all of my domains with minimal configuration?](https://serverfault.com/q/669819)
- [Why is geo-redundant DNS necessary for small sites?](https://serverfault.com/q/710108)
- [How do I set up a "secure" open resolver?](https://serverfault.com/q/634793)

### Licensing

- [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/q/215405)
- [Do I need a RHEL subscription to install packages?](https://serverfault.com/q/537568)

### Networking

- [Networking Units: Not getting expected performance from 100Mb Ethernet](https://serverfault.com/q/333816)
- [Loopback to forwarded Public IP address from local network - Hairpin NAT](https://serverfault.com/q/55611)
- [What tools can create a map of my network?](https://serverfault.com/q/2163)
- [What am I looking for in a Monitoring Solution?](https://serverfault.com/q/394393)
- [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/q/49765)
- [How does IPv6 subnetting work and how does it differ from IPv4 subnetting?](https://serverfault.com/q/426183)
- [Switching to IPv6 implies dropping NAT. Is that a good thing?](https://serverfault.com/q/184524)
- [How do VLANs work?](https://serverfault.com/q/188350)
- [Exposing multiple servers behind NAT using a single public IP address](https://serverfault.com/q/521618)
- [Connecting to a remote server through a VPN when the local network subnet address conflicts with a remote network](https://serverfault.com/q/548888)
- [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-messge)
- [How do I make protocol foo hostname-aware?](https://serverfault.com/q/878080)

### General Unix/Linux OS Stuff

- [Why is Linux reporting "free" memory strangely?](https://serverfault.com/q/449296)
- [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/q/449651)
- [Unix Server Partitioning & Filesystem Layout](https://serverfault.com/q/449395)
- [Install software from packages, or build it from source?](https://serverfault.com/q/671223)
- [Can you help me with my software dependency issue?](https://serverfault.com/q/489628)
- [Installing a third party application package on CentOS 6.4 fails due to missing dependencies libcrypto.so.10 and libssl.so.10](https://serverfault.com/q/563051)
- [Why drop caches in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/597115)

### Security

- [Heartbleed: What is it and what are options to mitigate it?](https://serverfault.com/q/587329)
- [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/q/218005)
- [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/q/357108)
- [What should I do about a "misbehaving" user?](https://serverfault.com/q/323706)
- Restricted Shell: [How to restrict the users' shell allowing to execute shell programs](https://serverfault.com/q/89778)
- [How to convince a big boss that he does not need administrator privileges?](https://serverfault.com/q/40764)
- [Tips for Securing a LAMP Server](https://serverfault.com/q/212269)
- [How do I deal with the removal/eradication of an unknown worm on our network?](https://serverfault.com/q/339552)
- [Why is "chmod -R 777 /" destructive?](https://serverfault.com/q/364677)
- [I am under DDoS. What can I do?](https://serverfault.com/q/531941)

### SSH

- [Does getting disconnected from an SSH session kill your programs?](https://serverfault.com/q/463366)
- ProxyCommand: [How to configure a shortcut for an SSH connection through a SSH tunnel](https://serverfault.com/q/48808)

### Terminal Server (RDS)

- [Find out the bottleneck for windows remote desktop server (Terminal server)](https://serverfault.com/q/332622)

### Uptime

- [100% uptime for a web application](https://serverfault.com/q/316637)
- [reaching 99.9999% uptime](https://serverfault.com/q/130300)

### Virtualization

- [Enabling hardware virtualisation BIOS; anything to beware?](https://serverfault.com/q/7690)

### Web Servers

- mod_rewrite: [Everything you wanted to know about mod_rewrite rules but were afraid to ask](https://serverfault.com/q/214512)
- Picking the right MPM (on *NIX systems): [How do I select which Apache MPM to use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/383526)
- One-click (x)AMP: [Why not use a WAMP stack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/453617/why-not-use-a-wamp-stack), Meta: [What to do with XAMPP/MAMP/WAMP questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1968)
- IIS7: [What are the differences between Websites, Directories, Virual Directories, and Applications in IIS 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/108545)
- SNI: [Multiple SSL domains on the same IP address and same port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/109800)
- Host Header vs. DNS: [How does pointing a CNAME on my domain to a service-provider's server enable them to offer customized services?](https://serverfault.com/q/342999/152073)
- Reverse proxy: [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

### Windows (General)

- Host files: [Hosts file ignored, how to troubleshoot](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot)

### Law

- [Can you help me with my GDPR issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/908181/can-you-help-me-with-my-gdpr-issue/908182)

### Meta

- [Why SF is failing - the dismal future of ServerFault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5763/why-sf-is-failing-the-dismal-future-of-serverfault)
- [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts)

Comment: Just reading through these has increased my knowledge, we should make these more prominent.

Comment: What an awesome list... I'm a developer turned business owner/IT noob and came across this while looking for some basic info... this will keep me busy for a LONG time!

Comment: "How to stop people from using my domain to send spam? [duplicate]" surely shouldn't be on this list. Or is it a shining example of the perfect duplicate? The answer it is apparently a duplicate of doesn't address the original problem at all, so it probably isn't that.

Comment: This makes it seem like the ability to have tags for answers would be good.

Answer (score 22):

List of Canonical Topics that do not have a Q/A yet or need improvement:

#### Career

- When does my small business need a SA
- How many users/servers/whatever should a SA be responsible for
- [How do I protect my company from my IT guy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/283909/how-do-i-protect-my-company-from-my-it-guy)
- "Our previous specialist left, HALP?"
- Value of Certifications?

#### Datacenter Design

- [What to look for in a server rack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/470534/what-to-look-for-in-a-server-rack)
- [Physical server security](https://serverfault.com/questions/4788/physical-server-security)
- [What Data Center room routine maintenance tasks should be done?](https://serverfault.com/q/476918/33417)

#### Infrastructure Software

- [How is DNS related to Active Directory and what are some common configurations that I should be aware of?](https://serverfault.com/q/441191/10472)

#### Networking

- [Find out the bottleneck for windows remote desktop server (Terminal server)](https://serverfault.com/q/332622)
- Firewall Theory

  - Depth of Defense : [Several border firewalls in the same network](https://serverfault.com/q/459286)
  - IDS/IPS?
  - DLP/ILP?
- Cabling...

  - [I've inherited a rat's nest of cabling. What now?](https://serverfault.com/questions/420877)
  - [How do you organise the cables in your racks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/26462/how-do-you-organise-the-cables-in-your-racks)
- IPv6

  - Addressing (may roll into [How does IPv6 subnetting work and how does it differ from IPv4 subnetting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting/486462#486462))

    - [How do you set up IPv6 alongside an IPv4-based NAT configuration?](https://serverfault.com/questions/262370/how-do-you-set-up-ipv6-alongside-an-ipv4-based-nat-configuration)
    - [IPv6 without nat but what about an isp change?](https://serverfault.com/questions/349950/ipv6-without-nat-but-what-about-an-isp-change)
    - [Do all IPv4 IP addresses have an IPv6 equivalent?](https://serverfault.com/questions/216561/do-all-ipv4-ip-addresses-have-an-ipv6-equivalent)
    - [IPv6 configuration for my private network when prefix delegation is not supported by the provider?](https://serverfault.com/questions/477267/ipv6-configuration-for-my-private-network-when-prefix-delegation-is-not-supporte)
    - [What is the IPv6 equivalent to IPv4 RFC1918 addresses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/216602/what-is-the-ipv6-equivalent-to-ipv4-rfc1918-addresses)
  - Tunneling

    - [Teredo - how to connect to host behind NAT?](https://serverfault.com/questions/431105/teredo-how-to-connect-to-host-behind-nat)
    - 6to4
    - 6RD
    - ISATAP
  - Support

    - [How do IPv4 only applications work on IPv6 only hosts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/355424/how-do-ipv4-only-applications-work-on-ipv6-only-hosts)
    - [Are many IP addresses on a single interface a bad thing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/457546/are-many-ip-addresses-on-a-single-interface-a-bad-thing)
    - [Can a global IPv6 address be NAT'd to an internal IPv4 address at a firewall-level?](https://serverfault.com/questions/465502/can-a-global-ipv6-address-be-natd-to-an-internal-ipv4-address-at-a-firewall-lev)
    - [Should I use IPv6 only or both IPv4 and IPv6 in my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/421445/should-i-use-ipv6-only-or-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-in-my-web-server)

#### Web Servers

- Apache vHost
- Apache .htaccess/overrides

#### Enterprise Storage

Create one or more Question that covers "ES" topics... not sure how this should be organized exactly. Merge these answers into that Question(s) (keeping them separate/complete answers).

- [What is a Storage Area Network, and which benefits does it have over different storage solutions?](https://serverfault.com/q/425335)
- [What is the difference between SAN, NAS and DAS?](https://serverfault.com/q/81723)
- [Why is Enterprise Storage so expensive?](https://serverfault.com/q/263694)
- [How should I set up my Fibre Channel (FC) network?](https://serverfault.com/q/390493)
- [Tuning iSCSI storage](https://serverfault.com/q/389725)
- [2.5 inch drives versus 3.5 inch drives](https://serverfault.com/q/351924)
- [Reliability of ssd drives](https://serverfault.com/q/14189)
- [How can I safely use storage thin provisioning?](https://serverfault.com/q/591125)

#### Server Hardware

- [What RAM options do I need to know before buying Server RAM?](https://serverfault.com/q/618102)
- [What is the Rowhammer DRAM bug and how should I treat it?](https://serverfault.com/q/674214)

Comment: "Our previous specialist left, HALP?" and "How many users/servers/whatever should a SA be responsible for" would most likely be too broad.  The 1st one doesn't specify what kind of specialist, and the 2nd is completely dependent on type of environment and who the SA is.  Just can't see either being canonical if they are mostly opinion.

Answer (score 7):

In response to [Why The Hostility](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5337/why-the-hostility), I wrote this for consideration as a canonical Q/A:

[What are the basics of running a Web Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/497246/what-are-the-basics-of-securing-a-web-server)