# Best 'restricted shell' question

Tags: discussion

This is one that crops up often:

[How to restrict the users' shell allowing to execute shell programs](https://serverfault.com/questions/89778/how-to-restrict-the-users-shell-allowing-to-execute-shell-programs)

But is it the best example we can find of a 'canonical' question on which we can close duplicates?

Comment: Huh, missed that one the first time around.

Comment: I added an answer since it was missing that particular information.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the question has been merged into the list of [canonical answers](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) we have discovered.