# Serverfault, superuser, or nowhere?

Tags: discussion, serverfault, allowed-topics, super-user

I have a question that I'd like to post, which is *entirely* business related, which concerns connecting a home worker to a corporate network using an ADSL router with a VPN client built in to it. The problem is specific to the Home User's ADSL modem, as the VPN server on the corporate network, is working fine.

As it is a question that is business related, I would have normally posted it here, but then I remembered the statement `Anything in a home setting. No exceptions` in the FAQ rewrite.

So, having checked on superuser, their FAQ states that questions relating to `issues specific to corporate IT support and networks` are off topic.

Technically, according to both FAQs, my question is off topic on both sites.

I can work around this problem by disguising the `Home Worker` as `Remote Worker` and post here on SF, alternatively neglect to mention this is in a business environment and post on SU, but where is the correct place for this question? Is it actually welcome on any of the SE sites?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My thought is that this is something we deal with as administrators of business networks, and as such would fall in scope of SF. The part of the FAQ that you're referring to is for people that tinker with servers and such at home, but don't do it in a professional capacity. I think it would be fine here. Better than SU, for sure.

Answer (score 11):

Remote worker/teleworker at home isn't "home usage" *per se*, so SF is fine.

Comment: Right. The teleworker is still in their "office", it just happens to also be their home.

Comment: @ChrisS "Anything in a home setting. No exceptions". Is a teleworker an exception to "no exceptions" rule?

Comment: Per my answer below, a teleworker isn't in a "Home Setting", their location happens to be a home but that isn't the same. Perhaps we need some fine print to flesh out the nuances...

Answer (score 8):

For the context of such questions the "home" user is effectively a remote office. Most of us would recognise this immediately but some would still see "home" and cast a knee-jerk vote. I therefore suggest you avoid attracting unnecessary attention to the home aspect by simply neglecting to mention it and discuss it as a remote office.

Answer (score 7):

> Anything in a home setting. No exceptions

This isn't a "home setting", it's a location that happens to also be a home. This is a corporate use of the location, as you have described it, and so fits within our FAQ, also out of SU's FAQ as you have noted.