# Can ownership of question be manually replaced?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I refer to this question: [Command line to list users in a Windows Active Directory group?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49405/command-line-to-list-users-in-a-windows-active-directory-group) - once upon a time a driveby question by a user that no longer exists in the system.

The quetsion has 117kviews, so it's obviously a very popular question. But its accepted answer is clearly not the best one. In fact there are two other answers with more upvotes.

Is there any way that the ownership of this question can be assigned or the accepted answer changed? I'm afraid that 117,000 people will not be receiving an optimal experience when coming on to the site with this accepted answer.

(note: normally I would prompt the OP to consider changing their checkmark, but obviously this is impossible now. Normally this would not worry me, but 117k is a *lot* of people)

Comment: As a moderator you could theoretically delete the accepted answer, but you cannot remove the acceptance from the post. Whether it is a good idea to do that is a different question.

Comment: @MadScientist - actually I don't think I can delete accepted answers either

Comment: Regular users can't, diamond moderators can delete accepted answers.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit and improve the answer instead?

Comment: Still my preferred answer: [What to do with an accepted answer which is plainly wrong?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3658/what-to-do-with-an-accepted-answer-which-is-plainly-wrong/3660#3660)

Comment: If the ownership can be changed it should be changed to "community", just to keep things neutral.

Comment: @jokerdino, editing a question or answer in a way that changes its intent or meaning is *never* a good thing to do, regardless of how much it may be improved by editing.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers - i agree. Or even a new dummy user created specifically for owning that question

Comment: @jokerdino - as John mentions, editing is generally done to fix syntactical/grammatical/spelling errors, not to append/change the actual answer itself. It would be unfair to the person who posted the answer to go and totally change it under the premise of "He's wrong" (he's not wrong, there's just better answers)

Answer (score 1):

There's a larger question here: What to do with content from deleted users?

My own suggestion is to do two things:

1. Remove any accept flags that the deleted user may have placed.
2. Convert all of their questions and answers to CW.