# Where can I find all Wiki Answers?

Tags: support

I'm currently looking through this site for research purposes, This may be very obvious to which I'll feel very stupid but I cant seem to find a way to see all wiki questions and answers together so that I can scroll through them for information. Is there a way I can view them all?

Comment: Do you mean [What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years?rq=1) as Community Wiki seems to have died a death.

Comment: @tombull89 CW is back in [vogue](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/)

Comment: The Community Wiki is back, but I'm not sure about being "in vogue". CWs are mostly ancient crap, most of which shouldn't be Wikis. The Canonical Q&As are our best source of good information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to look at the [search documentation](https://serverfault.com/help/searching)

> Boolean Operators
>   The following search operators can be used with values of yes/no, true/false, or 1/0 (each pair behaves the same):
>   ...
>   wiki: yes/true/1 returns only community wiki posts; no/false/0 returns only non-community wiki posts.

So something like [`is:question wiki:1`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+wiki%3A1)
Would find all Community Wiki questions.

Similarly [`is:answer wiki:1`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+wiki%3A1) will return only answers that are Community Wiki

and

[`wiki:1`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=wiki%3A1) will return anything that is Community Wiki.

Comment: these work a treat thanks for that :)

Comment: @lain Why to make things complicated when it could be simpler ? Sysadmins in there should just add a quick shortcut with a "wiki" button, just like "Questions" "Tags" "Users" etc... are