# Publish private Lan services over Internet

Tags: discussion

`How to access my internal network services from outside my local network ?`

This is a redundant question i can see on SF, mainly regarding Web Server publication from Lan to Internet.

From now, i admit i am a bit tired of reading this kind of question again and again, with, of course, mainly the same answer : `NAT / Port Forwarding`.

For sure, each case may have its own specific problem, but for a so generic question like `How to make my website reachable from Internet ?` i would vote to close immediatly.

IMHO this kind of question shows a lack of research from OP, as Googling a bit gives more than clues, providing tutorials for most standard network design.

How do we have to deal with it ?

- Writing a definitive community Wiki to refer to ?
- Close it immediatly as `managing information technology systems in a business environment` ?
- Continue as it is actually... ?

I am interested in your opinion.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50116/131874 - and that list hasn't been updated in almost 3 years...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question as posted truly only amounts to:

> How to access my internal network services from outside my local
>   network ?

...showing no other evidence of research or attempts at self-resolution, then yes it should be closed as this OT reason:

[image]

If it does show evidence of research, then it should either be answered or closed as a duplicate of a yet-to-be-written canonical QA.

Comment: How would you judge this http://serverfault.com/questions/690485/how-to-make-a-request-to-a-machine-on-a-private-network#comment850611_690485 ?

Comment: Doesn't show any research effort, and also no evidence that this is actually about managing systems in a business environment. I placed the fifth (and final) close vote.

Comment: +1 we are following the same way.

Comment: by the way i don't speak in here about "why this was not closed by Mod own decision" regarding reasons you gave...ps : don't consider i don't want to help! I WANT ! i just don't want to loose my time :)

Comment: Use SE enough and that'll happen. I've had many answers "stepped on" by close votes. Don't worry about it. Soon you'll be able to look at a question and tell whether or not it's going to be closed. If it's going to be closed, then don't bother answering.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just realise that my question was poor for community, but usefull to me, just as your answer and your time was. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

We already have [a list of canonical questions and answers](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/126632), which are meant to be comprehensive answers to commonly asked questions.

If such a question already exists, you can mark the question as a duplicate of it.

If not, then anyone can nominate (or write) a question for the canonical list. We would prefer to have extensive answers which cover as much of the topic as possible, to include as many possible variations of the same question.