# Can I open a question about licensing?

Tags: discussion

I would like to open a question about VMware Essentials Kits licensing but, searching through the community I've found this: [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Which lead me to confusion, if it's offtopic or not to open those kind of questions in Serverfault.

I think, that's too vague to limit all the licensing question to just this one, there are a lot of specific cases that would be discussable.

Comment: Seriously, someone down voted for this? I was asking to keep the community clean and someone downvoted.

Comment: Downvotes on meta don't change your reputation and are mostly used to signal agreement or disagreement, so in this case read it as "I don't think such a question would be a good idea here".

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão Sadly the tooltips when hovering over the upvote and downvote arrows in meta don't appear to be accurate. At least, they're not accurate based on previous discussions about what votes on meta mean. It's not to be taken in the same way as votes on the main site. Sven explained it right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for asking!

Every software licensing question will be closed as duplicate of this question, as we indeed consider this off-topic.

Licensing is always extremely localized and more of a subject for lawyers then anyone else. When in doubt, contact the vendor, he is the only one who can give you a guaranteed correct answer.

Comment: Thank you Sven. Just a dumb question, there is any site on the StackExchange community to ask questions like this? Or we are out of help over here?

Comment: Well, the very reasons outlined in http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue makes this as impractical to answer on any other site. Licensing is a difficult topic and potentially expensive if you don't get it right, so just ask the vendor and be on the safe side.

Comment: Vinicius, you should probably also understand the function of **canonical** questions on SF.  More can be found at http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years , if you're curious.

Comment: Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

It might be on topic at the recently launched (to public beta) [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).