# Should I flag bottleneck identification problems as Capacity and Planning dupes?

Tags: discussion

There are lots of [questions on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=bottleneck) (2.3k as of this writing) about identifying bottlenecks. I just came across [CPU overloaded but no proccess is using more than 1%](https://serverfault.com/questions/711644/cpu-overloaded-but-no-proccess-is-using-more-than-1) when reviewing, and I'm not certain whether or not it's appropriate to flag questions like this as a duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning).

I do see that there are two [canonical questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years/3387#3387) on bottleneck identification, which leads me to believe that there is a distinction drawn between the two in this community. I guess I just feel like there should be some canonical Q/A on bottleneck identification, like there is for capacity planning, and don't see the value in having so many different questions and answers concerning bottleneck identification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no<sup>*</sup>. Identifying a bottleneck is not the same as capacity planning. The canonical capacity planning question was put in place because the questions asking for capacity planning advice provide no information from which capacity requirements can be generated. Worse, the people asking aren't in a position to gather the relevant metrics even if you tell them what they need to collect.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>You don't actually ask any questions so I answered the question in your title</sub>