# Concrete question was closed with "too broad"

Tags: discussion

Just came through this thread: [Difference between Microsoft ADCS Standalone CA and Enterprise CA](https://serverfault.com/questions/826444/difference-between-standalone-ca-and-enterprise-ca)

For me the question doesn't look "too broad", because the answer is quite obvious for those who is familiar with the subject and everyone's answer would be very similar. It is not something "the difference between Windows and Linux", it is about the difference between CA types of a given product. Microsoft distinguish them (types) by a number of characteristics/features, and thus place them in different usage scenarios.

This is why I consider this question as "not too broad".

Comment: Such is very often the fate of poorly written questions. I suggest editing it.

Comment: I did it, edits are waiting for approval.

Comment: There's a huge difference between the question that was originally asked and the one you've turned it into with your edits. This should probably be part of our canonical questions and answers.

Comment: Agree, initial question wasn't very well (though, I constantly see them on TechNet forums). I posted here to get some attention because wasn't sure if edits will ever work (to help to reopen the thread). I'm not quite experienced with how moderation works on SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so we can wrap this question up, I'll add my comment above as an answer :

There's a huge difference between the question that was originally asked and the one you've turned it into with your edits. The question is re-opened and I've upvoted both it and the answer. This is now great material which I have added to our [canonical questions and answers](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/) question here on meta.