# Should a successful (but certainly perfectible) answer be made a community wiki?

Tags: discussion

I have written a answer that has become unexpectedly successful.

But I don’t think my answer is perfect, and some users made suggestions for improvement.

Would it be good practice to make this answer a community wiki, to let other users improve it?

(I know I wouldn’t get any more reputation for that answer, but I think I already got much more than I deserved.)

Answer (score 11):

IMO, I don't see much value in proactively making a post community wiki (and the option to do so in most cases was removed from SE years ago).  If others make suggested edits, you (or other high-rep users) can accept the edits, no muss, no fuss.

Answer (score 1):

The [only time](https://serverfault.com/questions/755654/which-rfcs-should-be-cited-as-internet-standards/755655#755655) I've ever used the community wiki feature was when the answer was a snapshot in time. As a general rule topics that can only be answered transiently are not a good fit for Stack Exchange sites, but there is the occasional exception.

I tend to agree with Womble that there are few scenarios where it's worth using the feature, especially if you're a low rep user who could benefit from additional site access. The 500+ Fake Internet Points forfeited in the above example don't mean much to established users on this site, but would definitely have been useful to others.

In practice, most of a community's wiki-like content ends up on the Meta site anyway. A good example of this is our [Canonical Answers page](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years).