# Is it time for a canonical question/answer on non-hostname-aware protocols?

Tags: discussion, canonical

After [yet another question](https://serverfault.com/q/876993/55514) asking how to bring hostname-awareness for proxying purposes to a protocol that doesn't have any support for it, is it time for a [canonical](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) question on hostname-aware proxying, plus a good answer on how DNS works, the few protocols that *are* hostname-aware and how they do it, and the impossibility of a general solution for all other protocols?  I'm happy to take a stab at a short question, and longer answer, but wanted to take your minds on whether it was desirable before so doing.

**Edit**: thanks to HBruijn and upvoters for support, and especially to kasperd for some excellent suggestions.  The QA now appears [here](https://serverfault.com/q/878080/55514), and people should feel free to amend/vote/mock as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up and the QA you wrote. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Good idea!

---

Answer (score 8):

I think it would be a good canonical question to have. I imagine the core of the question would be roughly this:

> Which protocols support hostname based proxying and what can I do if I need to support a protocol which doesn't?

But some context on why you would want to do such a thing in the first place could make it a better question.

The list of protocols in the answer would as far as I know amount to HTTP, SSL, FTP, DNS, and SMTP with a few caveats.

I think it is also relevant to have canonical questions about individual protocols for the most popular protocols. I have treated [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/34552/214507) as canonical for SSH. For FTP I think this is the [best answer](https://serverfault.com/a/672403/214507).