# Was this question wrongly marked as an exact duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [What file do I need to change so Apache won't say what Operating System I am using?](https://serverfault.com/questions/900805/what-file-do-i-need-to-change-so-apache-wont-say-what-operating-system-i-am-usi)

Several users had marked it as an exact duplicate, so I tried to search for a similar question, but was not able to find anything that resembled the question I asked. I asked for a link to be provided, to which there was no response. I'm wonderinf if this question was marked so that they wouldn't have to answer it, even though it was not a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

The link to the duplicate is displayed below the title and above the body.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Michael already showed you where to find the link so I will respond to your assertion that your question was wrongfully closed.

When a question gets [closed as a duplicate](https://serverfault.com/help/duplicates) it will get a text block between the title and the original question

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [title and link to another Q&A](https://serverfault.com)

And below the question the close reason:

> **marked as duplicate by [username(s) | moderator♦ ] on** *date*
>   This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.

The *”exact duplicate”* term is slightly misleading. Rather than that the other question is verbatim (word for word)  the same, the community members and/or moderators that voted to close a question may select the duplicate also because:

- the **same solution** from the linked Q&A also applies to your question
- your question is a variety of our [**Canonical Q&A**](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/37681) topics