# Why is this question off topic here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, review

I have reviewed this question and found it to be good. What are the criteria for setting it off topic?

[I am not able to access my web application outside VM using Web browser](https://serverfault.com/questions/940857/i-am-not-able-to-access-my-web-application-outside-vm-using-web-browser)

Comment: Hi, a note, wamp topic tend to fall offtopic there for another reason, for home and lab usage usualy, it might not be the case with the specific question you linked, but see that for info . https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1968/what-to-do-with-xampp-mamp-wamp-questions

Comment: If you found that to be a good question, perhaps you should not be reviewing.

Comment: @Iain After all, I asked for something to learn. And it's not about whether it was a good question (which it wasn't), but whether it's off topic. There are many low quality questions and answers that are nevertheless on topic.

Comment: Read your question above carefully - ' ... found it to be good'. It's a bit of a give away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the yellow box. OP doesn't tell us anything about his environment. It can be reopened when it is improved.

Answer (score 3):

However the close reason is clear and just, it seems a bit odd to put this under "off topic". The question is just lacking details, but that would be more of an "unclear what you're asking" type of close reason IMHO.

From the little details that are in the question, it seems to be about networking/firewalls on a Windows Server 2016 machine, so that would actually be very much on topic.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210314/189912